# SVG из Adobe XD имеет сдвиг и большой viewport

Tags: вёрстка, svg, adobe, illustrator

Работаю с макетом сайта, сделанном в Adobe XD.
Экспортирую оттуда в `svg` маленькую иконку, на выходе получаю вот такой файл:

```css
.cls-1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #1fe3a4;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-891.278 3726.142 4.615 7.629">
  <path id="Path_7" data-name="Path 7" class="cls-1" d="M0,0,3.549,3.461,0,6.912" transform="translate(-890.929 3726.5)"/>
</svg>
```

зачем-то viewport берется относительно какого-то другого объекта (или артборда), и path смещается, чтобы быть на своем месте.

**Вопрос:**
Как правильно экспортировать, чтобы начало координат было 0 0, и размер viewport'а был корректным?

Comment: Артур, вам дали вполне правильный ответ. Не надо [негативить, что кто-то не угадал ваши мысли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/802563/svg-%d0%b8%d0%b7-adobe-xd-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b9-viewport#comment1270684_802943) - попробуйте лучше чётко ответить на вопрос "что означает 'правильно' экспортировать"? В текущей формулировке вопрос непонятен - я проголосовал за закрытие, чтобы вы переформулировали вопрос, чтобы можно было дать объективный ответ. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Насчёт Adobe XD не знаю. `viewBox` можно изменить самому, а у `path` убрать `transform`. На картинке иконка размещена сразу в самом начале:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #1fe3a4;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M0,0,3.549,3.461,0,6.912"/>
</svg>
```

Местоположение иконки можно изменить другими способами. Можно использовать атрибут `transform`, или воспользоваться инструментами, которые меняют координаты `path`, вот один из них - [ссылка](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg_transforms).

Пример:
**P.S.** 20 по оси `X` и 10 по оси `Y`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #1fe3a4;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M20 10 23.549 13.461 20 16.912"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: svg картинка должна быть адаптивной, иначе зачем svg? можно было бы использовать png

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, убрал фиксированные `width` & `height`:))

Comment: а теперь представьте, что с из макета нужно экспортировать десятки таких SVG, а в дальнейшем некоторые из них используются как background (где важен настоящий viewport).
вопрос был в том, КАК корректно ЭКСПОРТИРОВАТЬ, а не отредактировать в дальнейшем.

Comment: @ArturValeyev, чем мог, тем и помог, изначально уведомил вас, что дело с Adobe XD не имел